# Exchange and Active Directory Displaying different users for the same group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

As far as I know exchange distribution groups are active directory mail-enabled groups (either security or distribution), meaning exchange groups and active directory groups are one and the same. The same goes with all identity objects (users\mailboxes and contacts).

With that knowledge I find it absolutely impossible that the same group name will have different group members between exchange and active directory.  As weird as this sounds I found such a thing:

```
PS #> $group_name = 'wrk_ek'
PS #> $ad_g = Get-ADGroup $group_name
PS #> $ad_gm = Get-ADGroupMember $ad_g
PS #> $xch_g = Get-DistributionGroup $ad_g.DistinguishedName
PS #> $xch_gm = Get-DistributionGroupMember $xch_g
PS #> $xch_gm.Count
4502
PS #> $ad_gm.Count
4438
PS #>
```

Is this possible or I am looking at corruption in my active directory\exchange? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

after carefully examining the results and comparing the outputs I came to conclude:

Get-ADGroupMember: does not return contact objects (as they are not security object- the powershell disregards them)
Get-DistributionGroupMember: does not return hidden mailboxes.